# Converting types in Scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion

What is the best way in Scala to convert:

Option[Int]

to:

Option[Long]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what `map` is for:

```
def convert(x: Option[Int]) = x map (_.toLong)
```

Which works like this:

```
scala> convert(Some(1))
res0: Option[Long] = Some(1)

scala> convert(None)
res1: Option[Long] = None
```

[`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html) provides an implicit conversion from `Int` to [`RichInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/RichInt.html), which is where the `toLong` method comes from.